# Mac Screensaver with WebView crashes

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, screensaver

Hy everybody,

I have a screensaver made with obj-c and cocoa. Everything works fine under OsX 10.6.2 except the following.
Within my screensaver I have a WebView with some application running. When I try to call my objective-c app (the screensaver) via javascript, I get an error and the screensaver and the system preferences panel crash.

> System Preferences[86666] 
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'
>
> reason: '-[NSCFArray drain]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x20049b1e0'
>
> *** Call stack at first throw:(
>   0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8123a444 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
>   1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff81f130f3 objc_exception_throw + 45
>   2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff812931c0 +[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 0
>   3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8120d08f *forwarding* + 751
>   4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff812091d8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 232 
>   5   WebCore                             0x00007fff847adee0 _ZN3JSC8Bindings12ObjcInstance10virtualEndEv + 48
>   6   WebCore                             0x00007fff8470d71d _ZN3JSC16RuntimeObjectImp18getOwnPropertySlotEPNS_9ExecStateERKNS_10IdentifierERNS_12PropertySlotE + 397
>   7   JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff80862b66 NK3JSC7JSValue3getEPNS_9ExecStateERKNS_10IdentifierERNS_12PropertySlotE + 486
>   )

I know this looks like some memory leak, but as you will see in the code, I really have nearly no objects allocated.

This only happens, when I start the screensaver with the "Test" button from the screensaver system prefs.
When I start the screensaver via terminal or if it starts automatically, the same action (calling obj-c from javascript) works fine.

Maybe someone has any idea, where the error could come from. Here is some code from the implementation:

```
@implementation ScreensaverView

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame isPreview:(BOOL)isPreview {

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame isPreview:isPreview];

    if (self) {

        [self setAnimationTimeInterval:-1];
        [self setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];

        // ::::::::::::::::::::::: Init stuff ::::::::::::::::::    

        // init 
        quitFlag = false;
        previewMode = isPreview;

        // find out the path the screensaver bundle
        pMainBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
        pBundlePath = [pMainBundle bundlePath];

        // read Info.plist
        infoDict = [pMainBundle infoDictionary];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)startAnimation
{   
    [super startAnimation];

    // combine: bundle path + filename for screensaver file 
    NSString *pathToScreensaver = [NSString stringWithString:pBundlePath];
    NSString *valueScreensaverFile;

    if(!previewMode)
    {
        valueScreensaverFile = [infoDict objectForKey:@"ScreensaverFile"];
    }
    else 
    {
        valueScreensaverFile = [infoDict objectForKey:@"PreviewFile"];
    }

    // add filename to bundle path
    pathToScreensaver = [pathToScreensaver stringByAppendingString:valueScreensaverFile];

    // complete NSURL to the screensaver file
    NSURL *screensaverUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: pathToScreensaver];

    webView = [WebView alloc];
    [webView initWithFrame:[self frame]];
    [webView setDrawsBackground:NO];

    // delegation policy for interactive mode
    [webView setPolicyDelegate: self];
    [webView setUIDelegate:self];

    // load screensaver
    [[webView mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:screensaverUrl]];

    scriptObject = [webView windowScriptObject];
    [scriptObject setValue:self forKey:@"screensaver"];

    [self addSubview:webView];
}

- (void)stopAnimation
{   
    [[webView mainFrame] stopLoading];
    [webView removeFromSuperview];
    [webView release];
    [super stopAnimation];
}

+ (BOOL)isSelectorExcludedFromWebScript:(SEL)selector 
{       
    if (selector == @selector(quitScreenSaver)) {
        return NO;
    }

    if(selector == @selector(gotoUrl:) ){
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}

+(NSString *)webScriptNameForSelector:(SEL)selector
{   
    if(selector == @selector(quitScreenSaver))
    {
        return @"quitNoOpen";
    }

    if(selector == @selector(gotoUrl:))
    {
        return @"openAndQuit";
    }

    return nil;
}

- (void) quitScreenSaver
{
    quitFlag = true;
    [super stopAnimation];
}

- (void) gotoUrl:(NSString *) destinationURL 
{   
    if(destinationURL == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    NSString * path    = destinationURL;
    NSURL    * fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
    [[ NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace ] openURL:fileURL];
    [self quitScreenSaver];
}

@end
```

I hope that's enough code for you to see some problems / solutions.
I would really appreciaty any answers.

Comment: Did you turn on the GC or not?

Comment: GC is on. Otherwise the screensaver would not work with OSX 10.6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somehow an NSCFArray (NSMutableArray) is being sent a "drain" message that's meant for an NSAutoreleasePool.

You might be able to get a bit more info on what the array is by implementing the drain method for NSMutableArray, so you can trap the now-recognized selector and print out the contents of the array object. Try adding this somewhere in your code:

```
@interface NSMutableArray (drain)

- (void) drain;

@end

@implementation NSMutableArray (drain)

- (void) drain
{
   NSLog(@"drain message received by object: %@", self);
}

@end
```

If you don't see any messages show up in the Console, try changing the "NSMutableArray" in the above code to "NSObject".

Comment: With overriding NSObject drain, the system prefs panel crashes no longer. The drain message comes from some strange preview image, most of the time a different one. Everything works great now.

Thank you!

Comment: Vote up because this is an answer I think one can always need if some strange objects kill your app, especially if the app gets executed by another one.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to be aware of is that when you start the screensaver via the "Test" button in System Prefs, you actually have 2 instances of your screensaver view running in the same process' address space on different threads.  One (with isPreview==YES) is the little preview in the SysPrefs window (which continues running even when the full-screen version is started), and the other one is the full-screen version.  They are both running in the SysPrefs.app process.  So, you have to be careful to check all Notifications/etc. to see if they are coming from the view instance you expect.

I don't see any obvious problems from a quick glance at the code you posted, but it may be somewhere else.  Do you use Notifications anywhere?

I put a similar webview-in-a-screensaver project on github at  http://github.com/kelan/WikiWalker, where I initially had some similar problems (though I wasn't using any javascript stuff).  It's not perfect code, but might help.  I also did some tricks to forward notifications to the main thread (for drawing) in a .  See the "Threaded Notification Support" parts of WWScreenSaverView.{h,m}.

Comment: I don't use notifications anywhere.
I checked the instances of my different objects (WebView, ScriptObject, self), but the instance, where the unrecognized selector is sent to, is something completely different. Is there a way to find out, which instances of objects are running and to get the name (e.g.: 0x200044820)?
The scriptobject is provided for JavaScript correctly, but afterwards, the sysPrefs crash.

Answer (score 1):

Something to try:

- Open up a terminal window and enter the following line to run System Preferences with [NSZombieEnabled](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled):

`env NSZombieEnabled=YES "/Applications/System Preferences.app/Contents/MacOS/System Preferences"`

- Perform the steps that lead to the crash.
- Run the Console app, set the filter in the upper right to "System Preferences", and look for NSZombie messages.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried that 2 times, but there are no NSZombie messages in my console. The error message is still "***Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException' - Unrecognized selector sent to instances 0x200472000***" . That instance number is non of my objects I think, at least not my mainview, webview or scriptobject.

Answer (score 0):

Just to troubleshoot, did you try not releasing the WebView?

Also, maybe set the WebView's delegates to nil before releasing it first?

Comment: Just tried that. The system prefs panel still crashes. 
And I think the WebView has no delegates.

Comment: In the sample code you posted, you're setting two different delegates on the webview.

Comment: You're right. I have deleted these but the crash still occurs.